# How to Check multiple lines of input with a list of data

Tags: java

I am trying to get java to take an input of x amount of lines and get it to check an if else tree for the output of each one. I can only get it to check one line of input though. Please help, I am new to programming Java.
This is what I have so fat:

```
package Javatest;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Jtest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Part Number: ");
    String price = input.nextLine();

    if("700212129".equals(price)){
        System.out.println("$280.00");
    }else{
      if("100010B".equals(price)){
        System.out.println("$52.50");
      }else{
        if("100030B".equals(price)){
          System.out.println("$7.18");
        }else{
          if("1189A-BELDEN".equals(price)){
            System.out.println("$140.00");
          }else{
            System.out.println("#N/A");
            return;     
          }             
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can use a look like `do{....}while(<condition>)`

Comment: Since you're using `equals()` on strings you might want to use a `Map<String, String>` instead of the "if-tree", with the map's key being the part number and the value being the price (ideally you'd use a better designed object to represent the price but we'll keep it simple for now). To allow for multiple requests you need to use a loop along with a terminal condition, e.g. `while( true ) { String input = /*get the input*/; if( "end".equals(input)) { break; } /*check the map here*/ }`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to extract logic of each part. This is an implementation which separately initializes the list, waits for input, scrolls down stuffs and searches for code to extract the price.

```
package Javatest;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Jtest {

    private static final String EXIT_CODE = "exit"; 
    private Set<Stuff> stuffs = new LinkedHashSet<Stuff>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jtest jtest = new Jtest();
        jtest.initList();
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter Part Number: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inputLine = input.nextLine();
            if(inputLine.equals(EXIT_CODE)){
                System.out.println("Exiting");
                break;
            }
            String price = jtest.findPrice(inputLine);
            System.out.println("Price: " + price);
        }
    }

    private void initList() {
        stuffs.add(new Stuff("700212129", "$280.00"));
        stuffs.add(new Stuff("100010B", "$52.50"));
        stuffs.add(new Stuff("100030B", "$7.18"));
        stuffs.add(new Stuff("1189A-BELDEN", "$140.00"));
    }

    private String findPrice(String code) {
        for(Stuff stuff: stuffs){
            if(code.equals(stuff.getCode())){
                return stuff.getPrice();
            }
        }
        return "#N/A";      
    }

    public static class Stuff {

        private String code;
        private String price;

        public Stuff(String code, String price) {
            this.code = code;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getPrice(){
            return this.price;          
        }

        public String getCode(){
            return this.code;           
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very basic implementation but it can inspire you to build a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you want to do is learn about splitting/decoupling methods from your main. Its bad practise to just write all of your code in one place.

What i would do is write this in two parts:

First create a procedure to return a string from a single string input and include your nested if statement inside.

```
private static string GetString(string inputData)
{
         if("700212129".equals(inputData)){
            return "$280.00";
        }else{
            if("100010B".equals(inputData)){
                return "$52.50";
            }else{
                if("100030B".equals(inputData)){
                    return "$7.18";
                }else{
                    if("1189A-BELDEN".equals(inputData)){
                       return "$140.00";
                    }else{
                        return "#N/A";

      }               
}
```

Then in Main(), use a loop to constantly check any input you have typed, using a While loop would be a good example as you can use an escape clause to stop the loop/program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Part Number: ");
    String value = input.nextLine();
    String output;
    While(value != "E")
     {
      output = GetString(value);
      System.out.println("Value is: " + output);
     }
}
```

I would also suggest changing your nested If statement to a Switch/Select statement.

Comment: Typing "E" would obviously exit the program here.